# D: Not clear about how to use std.container structs

Tags: containers, d

I'm trying to learn how to use the various container structures available in std.container, and I'm having trouble understanding how to do the following:

1) How do I create an empty container? For instance, suppose I have a user-defined class `Foo`, and want to create an empty DList that is supposed to contain `Foo` objects. What's the syntax I should use?

2) Suppose `a` and `b` are both `DList!int`. I try to call `a ~ b`, and the compiler tells me I can't. However, I can see that `DList` has overloaded that operator. What did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways to create a new container,

1. the unified way, using `std.container.make`:

   ```
   auto list1 = make!(DList!int)();
   auto list2 = make!(DList!int)(1, 2);
   ```
2. using struct initializer syntax:

   ```
   auto list1 = DList!int();
   ```
3. using the helper functions for classes:

   ```
   auto tree1 = redBlackTree!int();
   auto tree2 = redBlackTree!int(1, 2);
   ```

The difference between those is that some data structures are implemented using classes and some with structs. And using `make`, you will not need to know but the first way as there is no effective difference.

Regarding the appending operator, you will need to append a range from `DList!T` rather than `DList!T` itself. Example:

```
auto list1 = make!(DList!int)(1, 2);
auto list2 = make!(DList!int)(3, 4);
list1 ~= list2[]; //notice the square brackets, which represent obtaining a slice (InputRange) from the `DList`, or more specifically calling `opSlice`.
```

As a more complete example on usage, check the following:

```
import std.container;
import std.stdio;

class Foo {
  int i;

  this(int i) {
    this.i = i;
  }

  void toString(scope void delegate(const(char)[]) sink) const {
    // this is a non allocating version of toString
    // you can use a normal `string toString()` function too
    import std.string : format;
    sink("Foo: %s".format(i));
  }
}

void main() {
  auto odds = make!(DList!Foo)();
  odds.insert(new Foo(3));
  odds.insert(new Foo(5));
  writeln("Odds: ", odds[]);

  odds.insertFront(new Foo(1));
  writeln("Odds: ", odds[]);

  auto evens = make!(DList!Foo)();
  evens.insert(new Foo(2));
  evens.insert(new Foo(4));

  writeln("Evens: ", evens[]);

  odds.insert(evens[]);
  writeln("Odds then evens: ", odds[]);

  odds ~= evens[];
  writeln("Odds then evens x 2: ", odds[]);
}
```

You can run this online here: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/f34b2ec8a445

Answer (score 2):

1. Depending on the container you want to use, there are typically several ways to create it. In the case of DList, the easiest way to create an empty DList which contains elements of type Foo is `auto foos = DList!Foo();`
2. Concatenating the two DList objects is unfortunately not as easy as `a ~ b`. First you need to make slices out of them, and then You need to use `~=` operator, so `a ~ b` becomes `a ~= b`

Here is some code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.container;

class Foo {
    private int _val;

    public this(int arg) { _val = arg; }
    public int val() @property { return _val; }
    public void val(int arg) @property { _val = arg; }
}

int main() {
    auto foos = DList!Foo();
    auto a = DList!Foo();
    a.insert(new Foo(5));
    auto b = DList!Foo();
    b.insert(new Foo(11));

    foos ~= a[]; // slice
    foos ~= b[]; // slice
    // writeln(foos[0].val); // "Error: no [] operator overload for type DList!(Foo)"
    writeln(foos.front.val); // prints 5
    writeln(foos.back.val); // prints 11

    return 0;
}
```

In my humble opinion, DList definitely needs improvements. - For an example, you can't get the length of it! (No comment) If you take a look at http://dlang.org/phobos/std_container.html , it clearly states that container primitives should have length property. However, *it does not state* that `a ~ b` should be supported! Luckily, Array!T does. Similarly, std.container page states that c[x] should be supported too (where c is a container type). In the case of DList!T it simply does not work.

I humbly suggest you use Array instead of DList. It should perform better (more cache-friendly), and it has everything we really need, including above-mentioned length property.

Let's modify the code to use the Array:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.container;

class Foo {
    private int _val;

    public this(int arg) { _val = arg; }
    public int val() @property { return _val; }
    public void val(int arg) @property { _val = arg; }
}

int main() {
    auto foos = Array!Foo();
    auto a = Array!Foo();
    a.insert(new Foo(5));
    auto b = Array!Foo();
    b.insert(new Foo(11));

    foos = a ~ b; // concatenation works, ah joy! :)

    writeln(foos[0].val); // indexed access! yeah! prints 5
    writeln(foos[1].val); // prints 11

    // Lets the user press <Return> before program returns
    stdin.readln();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Recent discussion on IRC provided an enlightenment - DList does not have certain operations (like indexed access) simply because that operation would not satisfy minimal complexity requirement (listed on std.container web page).

Comment: How do you remove an element from std.container Array? Like say the last one? when I try std.algorithm.remove or linearRemove I get compiler errors.